# c++ SIGCHLD create a wrong system call return

Tags: c++, system, sigchld

This is my code (it's just an example)

```
int a = system("pwd");
printf("pwd with return: %d\n", a);
cout << "errno is " << errno << "\n";

signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

a = system("pwd");
printf("pwd with return: %d\n", a);
cout << "errno is " << errno << "\n";
```

I just run "pwd" command using system call **before** and **after** "SIGCHLD" and I get two different result:

```
<actual path>
pwd with return: 0
errno is 0
<actual path>
pwd with return: -1
errno is 10
```

In both case the command is executed properly.

Why `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` creates this issue? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Be careful when using `errno`. Most calls only modifies `errno` if they fail, leaving it in an *indeterminate* state if they do not fail. Only check `errno` when the function is documented to set it (like when it fails).

Comment: You should capture the value of `errno` as early as possible, because other operations — such as outputting it to `cout` — may in the interim change its state.  You may want to `errno = 0;` before calling a function if you are not checking the functions return code for failure before looking at `errno`.